# Repeat process for image download

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am using Kingfisher framework to download images from the web and cache them. I have an array with a lot of Facebook id's, and the code needs to download the picture of each of them. Right now, the code downloads the picture for newArray[0], but it should do that for every id stored in the array.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newArray.count

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.kf_showIndicatorWhenLoading = true

    let URL = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/" + newArray[0] + "/picture?type=large")!
    cell.imageView.kf_setImageWithResource(Resource(downloadURL: URL), placeholderImage: nil, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: { (receivedSize, totalSize) -> () in

    }) { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in

    }
    return cell
}
```

}

Any idea how I would make it loop trough the code for every id and display it in the collection view? 
Any help is appreciated, really! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexPath.row` in your method.

Example:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/" + newArray[indexPath.row] + "/picture?type=large")!
```